# php namespace issue

Tags: php

Relative newbie to php, running into an issue with namespaces. Inside my own class within a custom namespace I am trying to call the native php ReflectionClass, but it is telling me that it can not find it within my own namespace.  How do I call the global ReflectionClass?

```
$reflectedNode = new ReflectionClass($obj);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$reflectedNode = new \ReflectionClass($obj);
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies everyone.  Really appreciate the quick responses.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP documentation has an FAQ that covers this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.faq.php#language.namespaces.faq.globalclass

Essentially you just prefix the global class name with a backslash (\) character.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix your name with a "\", like so:

```
$reflectedNode = new \ReflectionClass($obj);
```

Read [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.global.php).